# What's one way for recognizing an object (pre guidance for making a device)?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, avr, arm, detection

I want to make a device that will recognize an object, for example: cube, sphere etc. I have two sensors that make a pulse for measuring distance between the sensor and an object as shown in this picture:

[image]

Due to picture, T4 is the width of the pulse and the T2 will change due to object.
I can recognize the object by this amount. For this job, it is necessary that first I put the objects one by one under the sensors and save the amounts from the sensors (with the name of objects).

Next, for exmaple, for recognizing an objects, I put the object under the sensors and the MCU (or processor) says the name of that object. There are two sensors and the 100 objects. For each object I want to sample 20 times. Thus, for each object, I should save 40 amounts. Which processor or microcontroller is suitable for this job? AVR, ARM based microcontroller, FPGA... Any suggestion on a device to do this job?

Comment: Get this algorithm working on a computer before even thinking about how to embed it.  Your choice of embedded platform is not even close to the biggest obstacle to a proof of concept

Comment: This could even be done on a sub-MHz MCU with the right features...

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams How? i already tried to do it by an AVR but seems, in this case, the AVR isn't suitable.

Comment: @Scott Seidman How? but i don't choose a suitable MCU.

Comment: Personally, I'd start with some hardware like the National Instruments USB-6009 to work with your sensor, and get the data into a computer, or even something like an arduino and an oscilloscope that can save data to a USB thumb drive.  Create a data set that you can use to drive a data simulator, and work out your algorithms in Octave or Matlab.  Your question should be "can the data I'll collect with the sensor I have allow me to perform the task I need to do?" and you should answer that as quickly and inexpensively as you can before actually trying to embed.

Comment: Even if you start to embed this on a microcontroller to get the interface with your sensor correct there are many advantages to actually developing your algorithm on a computer and porting it to the microcontroller when its ready.  It's just a lot easier to see what's going on, try different things, etc, on a computer than on a microcontroller, which can be a very opaque environment.

Comment: @Scott: Rigging up all that external hardware sounds like more trouble than rigging up a micro on a breadboard, then sending the time delta measurements to a PC via UART.  I agree that the algorithm can then be tested there more easily, but the raw measurements can be made in a micro very easily.

Comment: Yeah, Olin-- I sort of backed off w/ the 2nd comment.  This is great for a parallel development effort, as I suspect there's a learning curve hear for the interfacing, which needs to happen on the microcontroller.

Comment: Are we talking about something like https://www.bananarobotics.com/shop/Sensors/HC-SR04-Ultrasonic-Distance-Sensor for the sensor?

Comment: I fail to see how you could actually make meaningful object shape discrimination out of only two pulses. Unless the sensor has significant DSP / recognition built-in, and somehow encodes macro shape parameters into the pulse train. Which seems weird -- if you had that amount of power, wouldn't you just output some object discrimination factors over an UART of some sort?

So, short answer: I'm not sure you can achieve your stated goal AT ALL with the sensor you describe. If all you need to do is measure the pulses, any microcontroller can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are straightening deck chairs on the Titanic.  Lots of micros can so this.  That's not your problem.

First you need to understand the physics, the nature of the measurements, and what exactly you want to measure from the signal.  It is not clear you have a good grasp of this since you say *"T4 is the width of the pulse"* when it is clearly not from your own diagram.

You *say* you want to measure T2, and maybe that is correct, but are you sure you don't really want T1+T2?  Are these perhaps ultrasonic rangefinder pulses?

It would help if you said what the range of the various Tx intervals are.  If these are nanoseconds, then forget about it with your current level of knowledge.  If they are 10s of µs to ms, then you have a chance.

Many microcontrollers have a capture feature that can be used to measure the time between edges.  I am familiar with the Microchip PIC line, so I'd chose a PIC24H or dsPIC33F with a few "input capture" modules, which is most of them.  A snapshot of a free running timer is saved when the specified edge is seen.  By doing a unsigned integer subtract of the last  edge snapshot minus the previous edge snapshot, you get the time between the edges.

Comment: +1, although I would have thought straightening deck chairs on the Titanic was quite a complex engineering task at a depth of 3800m.